# How do I programmatically know the jQuery version using a script or a hook?

Tags: 7, hooks

How do I programmatically know the jQuery version using a script or a hook?

I have used this script for getting the site's jQuery version.

```
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {  
// jQuery is loaded => print the version
alert(jQuery.fn.jquery);
```

How could i get the same by using some database query or hook programmatically?

Comment: What do you mean by _query version_?

Comment: jquery update version

Comment: If you want to know [jQuery Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module version, you can write some code as like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3839647/377342) and get module version.

Comment: i am not asking for module version i just want to know which jquery version my current site is having

Comment: When I asked, you said _jquery update version_; now, it comes out you want to know the jQuery version, which is something totally different. The fact you are using the jQuery Update module doesn't change how to get the jQuery version, if not for a detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code to get all installed modules list

```
module_load_include('inc', 'update', 'update.report');
$available = update_get_available(TRUE);
$data = update_calculate_project_data($available);
dpm($data);  // provides installed modules details as an array
dpm($data['jquery_update']['existing_version']); // provides jquery_update module existing version
```

Comment: but it is giving wrong version detail i have used jquery version 1.7 but its giving 2.7

Comment: i think its showing module version i want to fetch detail which version is selected in jquery update module (eg:1.5 to 1.10)

Comment: $jquery_version = variable_get('jquery_update_jquery_version');

Comment: tx bro its working now .